# Excluding Rows Based on Column Contents

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a query which will exclude rows based on their common value in a particular column if a value in another column exists. Essentially:

SELECT Phone, Name, Age
FROM Customer
WHERE etc etc etc

What I would like to do is: If, for example, one customer's information would be: 111-222-3333, Rick, 45, and for whatever reason 45 is the particular value for which if it exists, I'd like to exclude all subsequent rows which match that corresponding telephone number, how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Always best to show a table of input and the expected output in these cases to clarify the requirements

Comment: group by, and having count(*) > 1 - thats a start - then make that into a subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` may work here,

```
SELECT Phone, Name, Age
FROM Customer C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Customer M
    WHERE M.Age = 45 AND M.Phone = C.Phone
)
```